# What is meant by "Kelvin connected to capacitor" in layout terms?

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, buck, layout, feedback

In the [MPS5496 PMIC layout guidelines on page 37,](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP5496GR/document_id/6906/) they mentioned that you should connect the feedback pins to the buck output capacitor "kelvin connected."  What does that mean? Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Same as what they always mean for Kelvin connection which comes up if you Google it. Do not share the trace sending back the measurement with any other trace that is carrying current. That's why it's drawn to split right at the measurement node on the sample schematic.

Comment: The are emphasizing that, for example for VOUT1, that the node where L1 connects to C6 is the point that's being regulated.  That being the case, any other point along the VOUT1 net is going to differ a bit from the voltage set point.